# How to execute a code after mail has been sent?

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to record a specific next-numbering on certain e-mails after I send them. However `Application_ItemSend` executes the code before it sends the e-mail.

I'm adding a reference number to the Subject, but I don't want to confuse everyone with random numbers appearing in their inbox.

Is there a way to execute code after the send?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it:

1. Declare a new type of events-related variable to ensure every time an e-mail is added to the "Received Items" folder an action is executed.

```
Private WithEvents Rcvditems As Outlook.Items
```

2. The method I used to avoid variables being restored to 'nothing' is using the same `Application.Item_Send` event. This option will ensure I activate my reader every time I send an e-mail.

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Set olApp = Outlook.Application
    Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Rcvditems = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail).Items
End Sub
```

... what it is doing is recalculating my variable 'Rcvditems'.

3. Finally, as Rcvd_Items is an event-related variable, I can assign event 'AddItem' to it.

```
Private Sub Rcvditems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
On Error GoTo EscapeSub
    Call MyMacro(Item)
EscapeSub:
End Sub
```

Like this I'm ensuring that I won't alter the e-mail when prior sending it, but just the e-mail that is added in the Received-Items folder.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the sent items are placed to the `Sent Items` folder in Outlook. If so, you can hook to the `ItemAdd` event of the `Items` class which belongs to the Sent Items folder. It is fired when one or more items are added to the specified collection. This event does not run when a large number of items are added to the folder at once (more than sixteen) - this is a known issue in OOM and exists in all Outlook versions.

```
Public WithEvents myOlItems As Outlook.Items 

Public Sub Initialize_handler()  
 Set myOlItems = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentItems).Items  
End Sub  

Private Sub myOlItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)  
 MsgBox Item.Subject
End Sub
```

Note, the [MailItem.SaveSentMessageFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.savesentmessagefolder?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaol11.chm1356);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue) property allows to set a `Folder` object that represents the folder in which a copy of the email message will be saved after being sent. So, it is not necessary that an Outlook item will be saved to the `Sent Items` folder if an add-in sets this property in the `ItemSend` event handler.